# how do android service react to unhandled exception?

Tags: android, service, location

I have a service that updates an internal database with the location which is then sent to a web database. After about an hour to 5 hours the application stops giving no force close and is gone from the task manager. how does the service react to an unhandled exception as it may be what is stopping my program?

Answer (score 2):

The service will gone, so this may explain your observation. If you can get at the logcat you will see the stack trace. Or try catching the exceptions and write some log to a file in the catch block.

However, if the service is not bound to an activity Android may kill the service if it needs the resources.

The following is an excerpt from here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html

> "The Android system will force-stop a service only when memory is low and it must recover system resources for the activity that has user focus. If the service is bound to an activity that has user focus, then it's less likely to be killed, and if the service is declared to run in the foreground (discussed later), then it will almost never be killed. Otherwise, if the service was started and is long-running, then the system will lower its position in the list of background tasks over time and the service will become highly susceptible to killing—if your service is started, then you must design it to gracefully handle restarts by the system. If the system kills your service, it restarts it as soon as resources become available again (though this also depends on the value you return from onStartCommand(), as discussed later)."